# Is a SQL db needed for retrieving data from a server?

Tags: php, ajax, json, mysqli, xmlhttprequest

Sorry but I'm a newbie to web development. I've been playing around with some JSON objects lately and have been using some example from W3school site - 'http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_example.asp.'

The example retrieves data from MYSQLi db and injected it into a JSON object. I've been using this example to create a dynamic site however my problem is I'm not sure if you need a db to store the data in the first place. Can JSON object be directly retrieved from a server?

The response from the server is parsed as a JSON object. i.e. var = JSON.parse(response)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>XMLHTTPREQUESTEXAMPLE</title>

</head>

<body>

<p id="id01"></p>

<script>

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "//http:URL";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }else{

                    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = "Server not responding";

                }

}

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

xmlhttp.send();



function myFunction(response) {

    var arr = JSON.parse(response);

    var i;

    var out = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Job Title</th><th>Room No</th><th>Tel Ext</th><th>Email</th></tr>";



    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        out += "<tr><td>" + 

        arr[i].Name +

        "</td><td>" +

        arr[i].JobTitle +

        "</td><td>" +

        arr[i].RoomNo +

        "</td></tr>"

                                arr[i].TelExt +

        "</td></tr>"

                                arr[i].Email +

        "</td></tr>";

    }

    out += "</table>"

    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;

}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The example php script on the server from the W3 school site.

```
$conn = new mysqli("myServer", "myUser", "myPassword", "Northwind");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT CompanyName, City, Country FROM Customers");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $rs["CompanyName"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"City":"'   . $rs["City"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Country":"'. $rs["Country"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It may help you get an answer quicker if you can post only the relevant portions of your code (unless the whole portion is indeed required for your question).  I am somewhat unfamiliar with this language, so it is hard for me to tell. You may want to take a look at the site tour on help --> site tour, you learn more about the site, and get a badge for doing it!

Comment: you did not mention if this works or not, even if it seems to work. If it works it shows that you can get data from your PHP-script and the PHP-script just outputs a JSON. How you create the JSON (by DB or not) is your choice.

Comment: no it doesn't because the php script is an example from the site. I was asking if you needed to create a db. Could you just not store a json object on the server itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example uses a MySQL database to retrieve data, but you can simply echo out your own data just to test your AJAX with JSON example like so:

```
<?php

$array = array(
"Key" => "value",
"Foo" => "Bar"
);

$jsonData = json_encode($array);

echo ($jsonData);

?>
```

Then you can retrieve the values in your Javascript's `myFunction` by doing :

```
arr.Foo; //would return Bar
```

A database is just for storing long-term data, it is not needed for the functional part of this tutorial.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been trying to do kind of. I didn't want to create a db because the data I wanted was just needed for displaying information, not keeping records. I wanted to make it dynamic so in the future lets say for example any changes needed to be made then I could just change the data in the JSON object without having to mess around with overall site. Im not sure if JSON is most useful for that but from what I can tell it can be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the most appropriate question would be, "Is a database needed for this type of data/application?" Or, "Should I use a db for this type of application?" Technically speaking, no, you don't need a database to store and retrieve information from the server, but depending on what you are trying to achieve, a database is probably going to be the wisest solution.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `json_encode($value)`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

this encodes an array into json object, and of course - you can store json data in any type of file, not only in database